# If $\int e^x\ dx = e^x + C$ What does the $\int e^{2x}=$

Tags: calculus

If $\int e^x\ dx = e^x + C$

What does the $\int e^{2x}=$

Please accompany answer with rule.

Comment: For the record, you wrote $\int e^{2x}$, but without specifying with respect to what variable you are integrating.  If you were doing $\int e^{2x}~dy$ it could be interpreted as the result being $ye^{2x}+C$, which is likely not the intended interpretation.  Don't forget the "$dx$" when writing an integral.

Comment: There is usually no implication like $$\int g(x)dx=f(x)\implies \int g(h(x))dx=f(h(x)).$$

Comment: @Surb, except for when $h(x)$ is constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $2x$ with $y$ :
$$\int e^{2x}dx = \int e^ydx$$
$$y = 2x \iff dy = 2dx \iff dx= \frac{1}{2}dy$$

Hence, $$\int e^{2x}dx = \int e^y \frac{1}{2}dy = \frac{1}{2} (e^y + C) = \frac{1}{2} (e^{2x} + C) $$

The rules used are integration by substitution and linearity of integration.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int e^{2x}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}+C$$

In general, for every non-zero $a$:

$$\int e^{ax}\,dx = \frac{1}{a}e^{ax}+C$$

I don't know what rule you are referring to, apart from a basic differentiation rule.